# utilizar clases aspx .net

Tags: asp.net

Quiero crear una clase con funciones para no tener que repetir código pero al intentar utilizarla me da el siguiente error:

> **Mensaje de error del compilador**: BC30002: El tipo 'Funciones' no está
>   definido.
>
> Línea 95: Línea 96: Línea 97: Dim dia As New Funciones Línea 98: Dim
>   mes As New Funciones Línea 99: Dim ntempo As New Funciones

**Mi código:**

```
Public Class Funciones
    Shared Function nombreDia(ByVal pfecha As String) As String
        Dim pndia As Integer
        Dim vDias(7) As String
        vDias(1) = "Lunes"
        vDias(2) = "Martes"
        vDias(3) = "Miércoles"
        vDias(4) = "Jueves"
        vDias(5) = "Viernes"
        vDias(6) = "Sábado"
        vDias(7) = "Domingo"
        pndia = DatePart(DateInterval.Weekday, CDate(pfecha))
        nombreDia = vDias(pndia)
    End Function
End class

    Dim dia As New Funciones
    Dim mes As New Funciones
    Dim ntempo As New Funciones

    lblfechacab.Text = Funciones.nombreDia(fecha) & " " & Day(fecha) & " de " & Funciones.nmes(Month(fecha)) & " " & Year(fecha)
    lbltempocab.Text = Funciones.nombreTempo(fecha)
    RecogerParamGen()
```

Comment: ¿Cual es tu código? ¿que intentas hacer? No tenemos una bola de cristal para adivinarlo.

Comment: Quiero crear un repositorio de funciones

Comment: Amigo, te recomiendo revises [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y luego te podremos ayudar, dado que lo que tu pides tiene 1000 maneras de hacerse, mientras tanto, es mas fácil corregir tu código que inventar uno.

Comment: Quiero llamar a mis funciones que he creado en la clase funciones me las reconoce pero al abrir en la web da error Mensaje de error del compilador: BC30002: El tipo 'Funciones' no está definido.

Comment: Amigo, ¿Puedes publicar el código con el que llamas a la clase?. si no me equivoco el error está en que no estas llamando un Webmethod.

Comment: No no estoy utilizando ese método como debería de utilizarlo?

Comment: tu código no corresponde a `ASPX.NET` .

Comment: esa es la parte del código .vb

Answer (score 0):

Hola ya he resuelto el problema en la parte `html` tenia que utilizar la siguiente linea:

> `<%@ Assembly Src="../includes/Class1.vb" %>`

Comment: No añadas información en la zona de respuestas. Edita la pregunta y pon el código allí

Answer (score -1):

Aunque no termino de entender del todo tu código , lo que estas intentando crear es una clase en la que guardar varias funciones e ir reutilizando las o por lo menos das a entender eso.

Mi codigo:

```
    Public Class Test
        Public Shared Sub Main()


             Console.WriteLine(MisFunciones.diaSemana(2))

        End Sub
    End Class

    Module MisFunciones
        Public Function diaSemana(ByVal pfecha As Integer) As String

         Dim dia As String
         Select Case pfecha
                Case 1
                   dia = "Lunes"
                Case 2
                   dia = "Martes"
                Case 3
                   dia = "Miércoles"
                Case 4
                   dia = "Jueves"
                Case 5
                    dia = "Viernes"
                Case 6
                   dia = "Sábado"
                Case 7
                   dia = "Domingo"
                Case Else
                    dia = "Error"
         End Select
         return dia 
        End Function

    End Module
```

Creo un `Module` que viene siendo el `static Class` de Java/C# , al que puedo llamar sin tener que instanciarlo. Luego creo mi función que a partir de un int obtengo el dia de la semana equivalente. Por ultimo usando un `Swtich` transformo el int a su homologo de la semana.

Espero que esto es lo que andas buscando , cualquier cosa no dudes en responderme.

Comment: Hola en local si me funciona. cuando me falla es a la hora de abrirlo desde el servidor que no recose la clase funciones.